# Why the max index of JavaScript's array is 4294967294 but not 4294967295？

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and recently met a problem about array of JavaScript.

The numeric index of JavaScript's array is described as 32 bit, I think its max index is 2 to the power of 32 minus 1，But the right is 2 the power of 32 minus 2.
I don' know why? Can anyone tell me?

Comment: How did you determine the maximum allowed index of an array?

Comment: @dogui i have try to use 4294967295 as numeric index of array,but i found that it will be dealt as string index when i output it by the method of tostring.So i determine its maximum index is 4294967294 but not 4294967295

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this to show you are correct about the max INDEX being 4294967294 since it is the max LENGTH -1 and the max LENGTH is 2<sup>32</sup>-1

So from 0 to 4294967294 you have 4294967295 elements

All JS arrays start at 0

`new Array(4294967295)` is the largest array you can define because you need to pass an unsigned int to the constructor Hence the largest index you can have is one less than that

> [**MDN Array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax)
>
> **arrayLength**
>
> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (**inclusive**), this returns a new JavaScript array with its **length** property set to that number (Note: this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values). If the argument is any other number, a RangeError exception is thrown.

---

> [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4,294,967,295#In_computing)
>   *The number 4,294,967,295, equivalent to the hexadecimal value 
>   FFFFFFFF, is the maximum value for a 32-bit unsigned integer in computing. It is therefore the maximum value for a variable declared as an unsigned integer*

```js
var arr = new Array(4294967294);
arr[arr.length-1]="one but last";
console.log("Length: "+arr.length,"Index = "+(arr.length-1)+": "+arr[arr.length-1]); 
arr.push("Last");
console.log("Length: "+arr.length,"Index = "+(arr.length-1)+": "+arr[arr.length-1]); 
arr.push("One too far");
console.log("Length: "+arr.length,"Index = "+(arr.length-1)+": "+arr[arr.length-1]);
```

Comment: @4castle I updated. You are absolutely correct

Comment: I know what you mean.But i don't know why array only have 4294967295 elements,32-bit unsigned integer have 4294967296 elements,from 0 to 4294967295,why javascript's array can't use 4294967295 as numeric index.I don't realize it.

Comment: Because all JS arrays start at 0!

Comment: i know array start at 0,but why can't use 4294967295 as index?if array use index from 0 to 4294967294，it just has 4294967295 elements.But 32-bit unsigned integer have 4294967296 elements, from 0 to 4294967295.Javascript's array can use 0 as index, why can't use 4294967295 index?Is the 4294967295 being used to another way?

Comment: See update. It is quite simple.

Comment: Wow...i see.I understand finally.Thank you very much.It puzzle me daylong.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array using the Array constructor you may supply it an optional length as follows:

The length of an array is a 32-bit unsigned integer. the length of the array may range from 0 to Math.pow(2, 32) - 1 which is 4294967295.

Comment: Stating explicitly that the OP is wrong would make a much better answer than just quoting a manual (which is what this reads like).

Comment: @deceze of course, while making it a much clearer answer it would also make it a wrong answer. The OP is right.